# Canvas Avoid jagged edges

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Good day with all:

I'm building an application for a dentist. I've used illustrator to draw the odontogram and export it with a well known plugin. The result was awesome. Then I start to explore the code generated by the plugin (about 3000 lines).

This is a portion of the code generated by the plugin

```
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(67.9, 113.9);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(67.9, 113.9, 69.9, 89.8, 67.9, 78.8);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(65.9, 67.8, 61.1, 58.8, 58.9, 55.4);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(56.7, 52.0, 54.3, 50.4, 53.6, 49.8);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(52.9, 49.2, 51.1, 48.2, 50.7, 49.8);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(50.3, 51.4, 50.7, 54.8, 50.7, 54.8);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(50.7, 54.8, 47.7, 54.0, 47.5, 55.2);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(47.3, 56.4, 47.1, 57.6, 47.5, 65.6);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(47.9, 73.6, 48.0, 81.4, 47.3, 86.4);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(46.5, 91.4, 42.6, 102.5, 42.6, 102.5);
ctx.lineTo(41.3, 108.1);
ctx.lineTo(47.7, 111.3);
ctx.lineTo(55.0, 113.9);
ctx.lineTo(61.9, 113.9);
ctx.lineTo(67.1, 113.9);
gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(63.4, 65.4, 53.9, 97.3);
gradient.addColorStop(0.00, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(1.00, "rgb(172, 171, 148)");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Artynok/qL79Y/4/

My idea was to colour every tooth as DB stored data was coming with the pertinent information (sick => red, healed => blue, external treatment => purple). I made a JSON obj to store all the coordinates of the gradients from this entire code, using some php code i could obtain all the gradient data (the ctx.createLinearGradient and RadialGradient ones).

After many tries to affect the code before the draw was made, I decidd to write the storing operation on my JSON, while the draw is happening. So when canvas ends to draw a part of the tooth, I grab the gradient coordinates, go for my OBJ that comes with the color states and match with it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Artynok/qL79Y/3/

Until here everything is ok except because the graph get the gradient but with jagged lines. I know that I'm redrawing over the tooth, even if the tooth have clinical state or not, because if I don't command to paint in the normal color, the rest of the teeth start to get the last color I've used.

So is there a way to "erase" the old Gradient to place the new one or change the color instead to redraw over it?

Comment: Thanks for an interesting, well asked question. Do you intend to save the image generated on canvas ?

Comment: Thank you!. And No, what I want to do is to show it on the screen without those jagged lines to make it interactive

Comment: Ok, this was just because @gernberg 's answer will improve the display only, you'd have to oversample yourself (draw on larger canvas, then draw it on the final one : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/qL79Y/8/ ) to be able to save a smoother image. Since you don't want to save, it seems you have your answer !

Comment: It works! but I have another little problem, i know i'm doing something wrong but I don't know exactly what is... Im using transforming points to calculate positions as mouse wheel do zoom and pan with mouse drag events. So when I look for this line in the canvas:

`ctx.transformedPoint(0,0);`

console it says _"undefined is not a function"_

Comment: Update: Ok I got it what happened here, and I'm afraid this can't solve my question. But you' were very close. Problem is the new ctx is just a "mirror" and transforming points "redraw" on zoom and on pan.

I pass a variable to "make it know" to my "draw" function (the drawing operation was encapsulated on a function), when an event (pan or zoom is happening, so the JSON have a flush function that erase all the dynamic data over itself, allowing transforming points to call draw everytime the event is happening Thank you anyway my friend!!

Answer (score 3):

There's one hack that you can try (which wont really fix the problem with jagged edges but improves the look on retina displays).

If you make the image 2x, and the via CSS resizes back to the normal size and it will look better.

JS:

```
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;
```

CSS:

```
canvas{
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#333;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qL79Y/6/

Comment: No problem, found when I was working with canvas on the newer iOS devices.

Comment: When doing this, one should take into account, that the coordinates will change and have to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to deal with quality in canvas when I was doing a progress bar plugin, truth is that canvas is raster graphics which means that the quality will never be perfect or very scalable. Since you are using illustrator to export the graphics, have you considered using SVG? It has pretty decent browser support and since it's vector the graphics are always the best possible quality.

Comment: I was thinking about SVG but truth is, I've had better luck with canvas. And I understand your app was using rastered images but this is 100% code.

Comment: @user3270814 You can generate SVG with code too, there are libraries like d3js and raphael. Also here's the plugin I've been talking about which generates SVG dynamically https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar

Comment: I have to +1 this answer too : <image src='myImage.svg'> is the only code you need to insert a svg. And a svg is structured (xml) and allows events : see §5 and §16 of the spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem. As I knew I was drawing many times over the same graph I did double check on the radial and linear gradient redrawing segment. My loops to play around with taht values were doing an unnecesary ammount of redrawings. I passed every value per segment in the draw operation one by one. This will take me too much time to rearrenge incode but the result worth it.

```
setGradient :   function(p,datos,z){//<-- now i'm passing the values instead to loop
        //dos caminos o radial o linear dependiendo quien tenga datos
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        d = 0;
        //for(z in this[p]){ <-- this was the cause of the pain in the head
            if(datos[p].estClin){
                //diente enfermo
                if(datos[p].estClin == "enfermo"){
                    if(z != "boundaries" && z != "data"){
                        console.log(z,p);
                        if(this[p][z]['linearCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['linearCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createLinearGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3]);
                        }else if(this[p][z]['radialCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['radialCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createRadialGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3],arrCord[4],arrCord[5]);
                        }
                        this.setColor(this[p][z].draw,grad,"rgb(255, 136, 136)");
                    }

                }else if(datos[p].estClin == "tratado" && datos[p].externo == "no"){
                    if(z != "boundaries" && z != "data"){
                        if(this[p][z]['linearCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['linearCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createLinearGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3]);
                        }else if(this[p][z]['radialCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['radialCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createRadialGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3],arrCord[4],arrCord[5]);
                        }
                        this.setColor(this[p][z].draw,grad,"rgb(93, 138, 232)");
                    }
                //tratado externo
                }else if(datos[p].estClin == "tratado" && datos[p].externo == "si"){
                    if(z != "boundaries" && z != "data"){
                        if(this[p][z]['linearCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['linearCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createLinearGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3]);
                        }else if(this[p][z]['radialCoord'].length != 0){
                            arrCord = this[p][z]['radialCoord'];
                            grad = this[p][z].draw.createRadialGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3],arrCord[4],arrCord[5]);
                        }
                        this.setColor(this[p][z].draw,grad,"rgb(142, 108, 209)");
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(z != "boundaries" && z != "data"){
                    if(this[p][z]['linearCoord'].length != 0){
                        arrCord = this[p][z]['linearCoord'];
                        grad = this[p][z].draw.createLinearGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3]);


                    }else if(this[p][z]['radialCoord'].length != 0){
                        arrCord = this[p][z]['radialCoord'];
                        grad = this[p][z].draw.createRadialGradient(arrCord[0],arrCord[1],arrCord[2],arrCord[3],arrCord[4],arrCord[5]);
                    }
                    this.setColor(this[p][z].draw,grad,"rgb(172, 171, 148)");

                }
            }
            //Aqui tratamos la info de los dientes a mostrar

        //}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Artynok/qL79Y/9/

Now grapgh are passing 99.99% clean but it's totally acceptable
Thank you anyway for everyone!!